# How do I add a passed in class to an element in a partial in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have a form for rendering multiple charts. I have multiple form elements for multiple charts, however the elements for each chart are the same. Here's a simplified example:

```
/ Chart 1, Question 1
%select.chart1Option
  %option{value: '1'} Graduation Date
  %option{value: '2'} Major
  %option{value: '3'} GPA

/ Chart 1, Question 2
%select.chart1Option
  %option{value: '1'} Count
  %option{value: '2'} Average
  %option{value: '3'} Median

/ Chart 2, Question 1
%select.chart2Option
  %option{value: '1'} Graduation Date
  %option{value: '2'} Major
  %option{value: '3'} GPA

/ Chart 2, Question 2
%select.chart2Option
  %option{value: '1'} Count
  %option{value: '2'} Average
  %option{value: '3'} Median
```

The only difference between the charts is the class I add, either `.chart1Option` or `.chart2Option`. The current solution works, but is not very DRY, especially with 5 charts, each having 6 elements.

How can I set up a partial so that I don't have to repeat each section and pass in name of the class I want to add? Once I set up my partial properly, how do I add that variable name as a class to an element in HAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract them into a helper. Mm, perhaps something similar to this? (Untested :P)

```
def question_group(num)
  q1_options = ['Graduation Date', 'Major', 'GPA']

  haml_tag :select, class: "chart#{num}Option" do
    q1_options.each_with_index do |opt, index|
      haml_tag :option, opt, value: index+1
    end
    # .. repeat 
  end
end
```

You could also DRY it via another partial and call that partial in the helper and put haml code in them.

```
def question_group(num)
  render partial: 'question_group', locals: { num: num }
end
```

HAML Partial

```
%select{class: "chart#{num}Option"}
  %option ..
```